# How far is $P$ from $AD$ in the parallelogram below?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: In the ABCD parallelogram, M is the point
mean of CD , BM and AC intersects at P.How far is P from AD; if B is 12 from AD.
(Answer:8)
My progress:

[image]

Draw $CK \\BF (K \perp AD, K \in AD)\\
\triangle ACK \sim APE \implies\\
 \frac{EP}{12} = \frac{AP}{AC} = \frac{AE}{AI}$

Extend $BM$ until $J, J \in AD \implies:\\\triangle BJF \sim IJK \implies:\\
\frac{PE}{IK} = \frac{JP}{IJ}=\frac{EJ}{JK}\\
\triangle BPC \sim JPA\implies \\
\frac{12-EP}{EP} = \frac{BP}{JP}=\frac{CP}{AP}$

...???

Comment: Hint: $CP:PA$ = $1:2$ as $DJ = BC$

Comment: @MathLover  grateful for the hint..I was able to see the solution

Comment: @MathLover  which ratio gives CP:PA=1:2?

Comment: Consider $\triangle APJ$ and $\triangle BPC$.

Comment: Or Apply Menelaus in $\triangle ADC$ with traversal PJ

Comment: (Too late to edit the previous comment). Observe that considering the triangles above directly gives PE, as those are corresponding altitudes(PE,PN).

Comment: @ACB  Exactly, if the ratio is 1:2 we will have 4 and 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint MathLover: $CP:PA = 1:2$
$$AP = 2CP\\\triangle APE \sim ACK\\
\frac{PE}{AP} = \frac{CK}{AC}\implies
\frac{PE}{2CP} = \frac{12}{CP+AP}\implies
\frac{PE}{2CP} = \frac{12}{3CP}\implies PE =8$$